# Void argument in function definition but primitive data type in declaration

Tags: c, void, kr-c

I have a query with below code. How does the below code gets interpreted as per K&R c? There is no compilation error and the code runs just fine. I have used **-traditional** in build option in codeblocks. Searched around for a while but could not get a satisfactory answer.

```
void func(int);

int main(void) {
    func(10);
    return 0;
}

void func(void){
}
```

Comment: `-traditional` only affect the preprocessor. the code you show should not compile.

Comment: In addition to other posts here: Don't write K&R-C code anymore. At least use C99, better standard C. Also note: K&R-C is **not** ANSI-C aka C89 (or C90, there are no differences in the language).

Comment: Why should you even think about something like this? function definition and declaration should have the same parameters. like @olaf said, forget that K&R even existed. Search on google about K&R erata.

Comment: You should use a proper compiler which does inform you about this =>> `error: conflicting types for ‘func`

Answer (score 3):

> How does the below code gets interpreted as per K&R C?

As code with a syntax error. K&R C does neither know about prototypes nor the `void` keyword (both were introduced with C89), so it is a syntax error.

Starting with C89, conflicting declarations are a **constraint violation** (fancy words for error) that must be diagnosed.